# Persistent Reusable JVM

Tags: zos, ibm-jvm

I am trying to figure out if the IBM Persistent Reusable JVM is still relevant and supported with latest Java versions. There is very little I find when searching on internet. There is just [this](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/servers_eserver_zseries_software_java_pdf_prjvm142.pdf) document that talks about it and it looks very old, it refers to JDK 1.4.2 and mentions that the -Xresettable feature is deprecated. I have tried using -Xresettable with JDK 8 and that failed as expected, that however doesn't mean the entire concept doesn't work and hence the question. We have a requirement where we want to invoke a JVM from C code and keep the JVM around and not destroy it for further request processing. Since the OS is z/OS which runs IBM JVM, I am trying to understand if the Persistent Reusable JVM is an option though my hopes are dim. If anyone knows about it, please let me know.

If it turns out to be outdated, I will evaluate other options of keeping a JVM alive, but that's secondary right now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is as you fear: the Persistent Resusable JVM feature never made it past Java 1.4.2.

If you haven't checked it out yet, look at the -Xshareclasses JVM option available in the more current IBM Java releases. It creates a shared memory cache of user and system classes, mostly with no impact to applications - somewhat similar in result to what persistent reusable JVM did, but without the side-effects.